# Use a range of date as type-selector in clearcase command lstype is possible?

Tags: clearcase

In order to use only one command to get all labels defined in the vob, plus their date and comment, I use the command below and it works well.

> cleartool lstype -fmt "%n;%d;%c" -kind lbtype -invob /vobs/myvob

Now, I would like to avoid to wait 13 minutes to get 40000 labels and I would like to get only the label created this month.

[Unfortunately a range of date is not allowed as the type-selector](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lstype.htm)

If I have to use another cleartool command instead of lstype, it is not a problem. I think about the command describe for example. But I didn't succeed to display all the labels in one shot with describe command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a pure `cleartool` command for this.

For your use case, I would make a cron batch in order to maintain (every day or more frequently) a list of all labels by date, in order to process that list whenever I need.

That way, you don't have to query labels, just to read them.
This is very much a workaround, but one which could be enough for now.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a replicated vob, try multitool dumpoplog -since. You will gave to manually parse the output, but it will give you the creation events.

Comment: You may also be able to use the output of "cleartool lshist -all" but lshist is expensive in terms of database transactions.